# What happens when we use vector erase or insert

Tags: c++, vector

Does it move all elements from the right side of the vector(to 1 position left if erase and move to 1 position right if insert) or is it like a linked list(it creates a new address and makes a new address.
Also when I initialise a vector with a string how does it take care of the memory.
If it is storing it in a sequence what would happen when we keep doing push_back when it reaches its maximum memory allocation.

Comment: If you care about speed, always benchmark, don't fall for the old "O(N) vs O(1) so O(1) is faster" trap.   In general, if you're using std:: and care about speed, vector is almost always the right option.  Every other container does "bad things" (where bad things means chasing pointers -- even things that shouldn't like unordered map)

Comment: You might want to watch _"Modern C++: What You Need to Know - Herb Sutter"_ from about 46 mins into the presentation: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661  Random inserts/deletes using std::vector vs std::list, the vector perform better up to 500,00 elements (approx) (also better than std::map)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `std::vector` is guaranteed (by the C++ standard) to store the elements in a contiguous memory area. Which means that no, it is not like a linked list, but more like a dynamically allocated array. When you push_back elements after the vector reaches the maximum capacity a reallocation takes place and elements are copied into the new buffer. Same happens when you use insert or erase elements, things are shifted around so those operations are in general O(N) and not O(1) as it is the case for linked lists.

So it looks like `std::vector` is worse than a `std::list`. This is not the case though as in many applications read operations are the dominant ones, for which a `std::vector` is way faster than a `std::list` due to cache locality and O(1) random access due to the fact that the elements are stored contiguously. Also push_back is O(1) except when the vector performs re-allocation (technically push_pack has amortized O(1) complexity).

Comment: Thanks, but how would it determine how much size it needs to allocate for a string, or does it just keep the address of the string?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by a vector initialized by a string? By a `std::string`? If it is a vector of `std::string`, then the allocator simply allocates the memory for `std::string` **objects** (which are all of fixed size, i.e. `sizeof(std::string)`, the latter takes care of its own memory for the string that it stores internally.

Comment: std::vector<std::string>

Comment: Re. "`vector` is faster due to cache locality": Yes, but also: random access is O(1) for `vector` and O(N) for `list`.

Comment: @alain Thanks, indeed, modified the answer.